# itms-services not work on ios11

Tags: installation, ios11

I have updated Xcode to **9**.
After I updated my iPhone to **iOS11**,I can't install my app (in developing) through **itms-services**.
But I can install my app using Xcode（by the button:run on device).
Other development devices (such like **iOS10**) still can install my app through itms-services.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "NO".